# Hibernate need full path for mapped class in query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

I have mapped class at path: `com.me.model.User`. And user DAO at `com.me.daoImpl.UserDaoImpl`.

The DAO looks like this:

```
package com.me.daoImpl;

//other imports
import com.me.model.User;

@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    //other methods...

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        try {
            return session.createQuery("from com.lime.model.User").list();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

}
```

My question is how to make hibernate to know the model object classes? I have import for `User` as you can see above, but I have to give full path in `createQuery()` method.

```
return session.createQuery("from User").list();
```

This shows error:

```
cannot resolve symbol User
```

Comment: Did you define the bean in spring configuration file ? show us the error stacktrace.

Comment: I didn't get exception, the upper code is working, but just need full path, and it's annoying to writing always the full path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map classes and packages in the hibernate configuration file like

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="com.me.model.User" />
```

To use this configuration with spring add this property to the session factory bean

```
<property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
```

The `hibernate.cfg.xml` should be on classpath.

Comment: I already have the mapping, this is working, but it just need full path (with com.me...) in query

Comment: This is annotation based napping you should use annotations on the class and I don't know which version of hibernate you use, because it requres annotation based configuration.

Comment: Well...I had made the mapping via spring as bean sessionFactory in property annotatedClasses, that's why it needed full path, but I added hibernate.cfg.xml as you sad and now it's what I want, but now there is a question what cfg to use for session factory, spring or hibernate? because i heard it's better to configure with spring.

Comment: If you are using spring you can configure `hibernate.cfg.xml` with it.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with Hibernate 5, make sure you use the correct JDK version.
I changed mine from 8 to 11 and it worked.

Also had to include `<mapping class="com.example.ClassName" />` in `hibernate.cfg.xml` file and viola, compiler didn't ask for the fully qualified name anymore..